# make div invisible and visible on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have one button and on the click of that button, i have one div to show and hide. i have achieved it using jquery. but problem is when page loads, div is already shown. and i want that, if i click on button then only div should be visible.

this is my code:

script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn').live('click', function(event) {

        $('#div1').toggle('show');

    });
});
</script>
```

html :

```
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btncss" value="filter" />
<div id="div1" runat="server"  style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:#f3fbd6">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" CssClass="btncss" Text="Filter" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS to hide it by default:

```
#div1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that jQuery's `live()` method is deprecated, and shouldn't be used. It was replaced by `on()`. Also, your `#div1` element has the `runat="server"` attribribute set on it, which means ASP.Net will automatically generate an `id` attribute for that element at run time. You will need to retrieve that `id` using the `ClientID` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    $('#<%= div1.ClientID %>').toggle();
});
```

Comment: @Satpal: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Cerbrus, OP is using ASP.Net so the ID of element might not be `div1` thus it will not work

Comment: @Cerbrus because when you apply the `runat="server"` attribute to an element, ASP.Net changes its `id` so that it can keep track of the element. This `id` is changed on each page reload, and won't match what you originally specified, so you have to use the `ClientID` property to retrieve it.

Comment: well i tried `on()` method, and it stopped working. versions issues??

Comment: Possibly, if you're using an older version than jQuery 1.7. If so, you should really update.

Comment: @Cerbrus completely. It's part of the reason WebForms is terrible.

Comment: yes sir i am using older version. so that `live()` code worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You should use CSS to set `display:none` to the `#div1`.
Use:

```
#div1{
   display:none;
}
```

Even though it is not preferred you can use JS to hide your div on `page load` inside `document.ready()`, so use `.hide()` and your script becomes:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
         $('#div1').hide(); //ADD THIS
         $('#btn').live('click', function (event)
            {

                $('#div1').toggle('show');

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Better to use `CSS` to hide

Comment: why is it better to use css?

Comment: When the JS is slow to load (Or has errors), this will result in a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

Comment: Yea it is better to use CSS, this is an alternative for that. But the OP asked for solution in JQUERY. Will update the answer though.

Comment: @NikhilBatra: If an OP asks for a `jQuery` solution to multiply `2` by `4`, wouldn't you tell him to use this amazing library called native JS?

Comment: @Cerbrus Got your point my friend that's why edited the answer and mentioned that :)

Answer (score 1):

As your `#div1` element has the `runat="server"` means you are using [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) so you should use [Control.ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx)

a CSS class should be used to hide the element along with rest of CSS rules

```
.myDiv {
    display: none; //Hide it using CSS
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#f3fbd6;
}
```

*HTML*, Add the CSS class to div

```
<div id="div1" runat="server" class="myDiv">
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$('#btn').live('click', function (event)
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
    //Or, You can use Control.ClientID
    $("#<%= div1.ClientID %>").toggle();
});
```

Comment: if i dont use runat="server' then i cannot use div1.ClientID right?

Comment: @DinavAhire Whenever you use server side control always use `Contol.Client` in JavaScript

Comment: if i am writing `runat="server"` , and not writing `div1.ClientID` , still i am getting my output

Comment: @DinavAhire, then somewhere `ClientIDMode` must be set to `Static` read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```js
$('input').click(function() {
   if ($('input').val() === "show") {
      $('#div1').show('700');
      $('input').val("hide");
   } else{
      $('#div1').hide('700');
      $('input').val("show");
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" class="btncss" value="show" />
        <div id="div1" runat="server" style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:#f3fbd6; display: none;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnFilter" runat="server" CssClass="btncss" Text="Filter" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

set `display: none;` for #div1 and use my script